# How to transfer bitmap using TCP socket

Tags: android, client-server, tcpclient, tcpserver, tcpsocket

I have the a Server/Client application in which i want to send and display screenshot of server on client. Can any body help me in that. thanks

The code is the following

Server side

```
public class ServerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView serverStatus;
RelativeLayout mainLayout;


// default ip
public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

// designate a port
public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private Handler handler = new Handler();

private ServerSocket serverSocket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.server);
    serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);


    SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();

    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    fst.start();
}

public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

                while (true) {
                 // listen for incoming clients
                  Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Connected");                  
                        mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
                            ImageView iv =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
                            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File file = new File(root,"androidlife.jpg");
                  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mainLayout.getWidth(), mainLayout
                        .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                  iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                  Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                  mainLayout.draw(c); 

                             //serverStatus.setText("Screenshot is displaying");
                        }
                    });

                    try {


                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                        //receive a message
                        String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        Log.i("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
                        serverStatus.setText("received: " + incomingMsg);
                        //send a message
                        String outgoingMsg = "goodbye from port " + SERVERPORT + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                        out.write(outgoingMsg);
                        //out.flush();
                        Log.i("TcpServer", "sent: " + outgoingMsg);
                        serverStatus.setText("sent: " + outgoingMsg);
                        //while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)      
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {


                                }
                            });
                       // }
                        break;
                    }  
                        catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// gets the ip address of your phone's network
private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
         serverSocket.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Client side code is:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

public EditText serverIp;
public TextView tv;

private Button connectPhones;

private String serverIpAddress = "";
private static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

private boolean connected = false;

//private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client);

    serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);
    connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
}


private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // if(true)
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
             Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                    //send output msg
                    String outMsg = "TCP connecting to " + SERVERPORT + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
                    out.write(outMsg);
                    out.flush();
                    Log.i("TcpClient", "sent: " + outMsg);
                    //accept server response
                    String inMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    tv.setText("message from server"+ inMsg);
                    Log.i("TcpClient", "received: " + inMsg);
                //  ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
                   // iv.setImageBitmap(bm); 
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            socket.close();
            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Is there an error, or do you not know how to accomplish some task? We'll be happy to help if you provide more details specific to the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see in your code where where you are trying to send the Bitmap of image or screen shot!! and you cannot send send a Bitmap over socket you should add this in the sender side after creating the bitmap b to create a byte array out of the bitmap:

```
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

In the server side receiver the bytearray and then recreat the bitmap in this way:

```
                Bitmap breceived = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you send first the length of byteArray created from bitmap?